# MySQL group by with condition

Tags: mysql

I have a problem of MySQL group by. I have a field called 'type'. I would like to make a group by of this field. Here is the examples.

| Amount | type |
| --- | --- |
| 30 | disable |
| 50 | V123 |
| 40 | AGA |
| 100 | V2594 |
| 30 | disable |
| 40 | school |

I would like to have the following group by

| type | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| disable | 60 |
| VIP | 150 |
| AGA | 40 |
| school | 40 |

which mean I would like to check if the type is 'V' for prefix. If it is 'V' prefix and the records will group together with new name 'VIP'. Otherwise just keep the same name.

Thanks you a lot.

Comment: You can specify in your select and in your group by: `case when type like 'V%' then 'VIP' else type end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use conditional aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT
    CASE WHEN type LIKE 'V%' THEN 'VIP' ELSE type END AS type,
    SUM(Amount) AS amount
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY 1;
```